# Text adventure game not reading input Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a text adventure game in Python. While I have two rooms programmed, north east and south east, and I try to make it so that the input should decide where you go, instead it just switches between the two even when you don't put in any input. Can anyone tell me what the error here is?

```python
name= input('Hello user, Welcome to the alpha! What is your name?')
print ("Welcome "+name+", We've been Expecting you!")
space = {"north": 0, "east": 0}
space["north"] = 1
space["east"]=2
def inst():
    print ("Type 'inv' to access your inventory")
    print ("Your name is "+name)
def move():
    command = input('Where do you want to go?:')
    command= command.lower()
def pie():
    if space["north"]==1 and space["east"]==2:
        print ("You are in the South east corner")
        print ("You can go West or North")
        inst()
        print (space)
        move()
        if "command" == "north" or "n":
            space["north"]=space["north"]+1
            pie()
        elif "command" == "west" or "w":
            space["east"]=space["east"]-1
            pie()
        elif "command" == "inv":
            inv()
        else:
            print ("What?")
            pie()
    elif space["north"]==2 and space["east"]==2:
        print ("You are in the north east corner")
        print ("You can go West or South")
        inst()
        print (space)
        move()
        if "command"== "south" or "S":
            space["north"]=space["north"]-1
            pie()
        elif "command" == "west" or "w":
            space["east"]=space["east"]-1
            pie()
        elif "command" == "inv":
            inv()
        else:
            print ("What?")
            pie()
pie()
```

Update: Thank you all for your help. I just wish to let you know that I have been taking codeacademy and I thought that I had learned enough. It's obvious that this code is a wip, but I hope that this will go better thanks to your suggestions.

Comment: There are a number of errors in this program. You need to read a tutorial and start a little smaller. Specifically, your move function doesn't return anything, you're overusing global variables, and your conditionals don't work the way you think they do (`"command"== "south" or "S"` is always `True`)

Comment: Open up a python interactive shell and type in one of your conditions like `"command" == "north" or "n"` and see what it returns. It is not what you think. What you meant to accomplish would be coded similar to: `if command in ('north', 'n'):`

Answer (score 0):

Your move() function doesn't return a value.  You have a couple of issues here that really strike to needing a better understanding of programming.  There are fatal flaws in your code.

1) def move() needs to return a value.

When you call it:

```
command = move()
```

The actual move function:

```
def move()
    command = input('Where do you want to go?:')
    return command.lower()
    # you could just make this whole thing "return input('Where do you want to go?:').lower()"
```

2) Each of your if statements should be:

```
if command == 'north' or command == 'n':
```

pattern.  Putting command in quotes literally asks if the word command is equal to the word north or the letter n.

That is just the start.  This code needs a significant amount of work.  Check out Codecademy or learncodethehardway.

Comment: For step 2, that will return either `True` or `n`. `True` if `command` is the string `"north"`, `"n"` if it is anything else.

Comment: Damn it Josh.  I was copying his code and not thinking :)  I will edit now.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious issue is you repeatedly make calls to `inv()` without declaring that function.

Second, I would recommend creating a `main()` function that has the main stuff in it, like the intro piece.

Big thing to read up on is functions, when to use them, and how to take advantage of return values to make your code more dynamic.

Finally, I second the advice given above. Touch up on the basics (Codeacademy/Learn Python the Hard Way), and use that knowledge incrementally to improve your program. Best of luck!